# not sure if versions of chromium & chromedriver stable for Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I've got chromium 32.0 and webdriver 2.9, but I got problems in the manner of

```
WebDriverException:"unknown error"
```

I can load the inital driver, do a simple driver.get('http://www.google.com'), but after that a total crash.
I can't be sure these version are the most stable , is there a way to be sure?

Plus the usual html of selenium the:

```
<html .... webdriver='true'..>
```

is missing from the webdriver.Chrome() I launch, which only a day ago was there.. is  it important the webdriver='true', or do you think the problems are not realted?

Comment: What OS do you use? If it's linux make you sure you have the right driver (32 or 64). Also you can try to update your driver to the 2.10

Comment: I have linux 32bit, the last release of the webdriver is 2.9, so I think its up to date.

Comment: That's actually 2.10 - http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.10/ I think you should try it